# Error in Dijkstra Algorithm while executing in removing the nodes

Tags: python, graph, tree, shortest-path, dijkstra

I am trying to implement the Dijkstra algorithm as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict
class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes = set()
        self.edges = defaultdict(list)
        self.distances = {}

    def add_node(self, value):
        self.nodes.add(value)

    def add_edge(self, from_node, to_node, distance):
        self.edges[from_node].append(to_node)
        self.edges[to_node].append(from_node)
        self.distances[(from_node, to_node)] = distance


def dijsktra(graph, initial):
    visited = {initial: 0}
    path = {}

    nodes = set(graph.nodes)

    while nodes: 
        min_node = None
        for node in nodes:
            if node in visited:
                if min_node is None:
                    min_node = node
                elif visited[node] < visited[min_node]:
                    min_node = node

        if min_node is None:
            break

        
        nodes.remove(min_node)
        current_weight = visited[min_node]

        for edge in graph.edges[min_node]:
    
            weight = current_weight + graph.distances[(min_node, edge)]
            if edge not in visited or weight < visited[edge]:
                visited[edge] = weight
                path[edge] = min_node


    return visited, path
```

I have 36 connecting nodes with directional weights. I have already made my graph. The nodes and connecting edges with weights are as follows:

```
print(g.nodes)
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 
 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35}

print(g.distances)
{(1, 7): 2, (1, 2): 2, (2, 1): 1, (2, 3): 4, (3, 2): 2, (3, 9): 2, (5, 11): 1, (5, 6): 1, 
 (6, 5): 3, (6, 12): 2, (7, 1): 1, (7, 13): 3, (9, 3): 4, (9, 15): 1, (11, 5): 3, (11, 17): 
 3, (11, 12): 2, (12, 6): 1, (12, 11): 1, (12, 18): 2, (13, 7): 2, (13, 14): 2, (14, 13): 3, 
 (14, 20): 1, (14, 15): 1, (15, 9): 2, (15, 14): 2, (15, 21): 2, (15, 16): 4, (16, 15): 1, 
 (16, 22): 1, (16, 17): 3, (17, 11): 1, (17, 16): 4, (17, 18): 2, (18, 12): 2, (18, 17): 3, 
 (18, 24): 1, (20, 14): 2, (20, 26): 1, (20, 21): 2, (21, 15): 1, (21, 20): 1, (21, 27): 1, 
 (21, 22): 1, (22, 16): 4, (22, 21): 2, (24, 18): 2, (24, 30): 1, (25, 31): 1, (25, 26): 1, 
 (26, 20): 1, (26, 25): 2, (26, 27): 1, (27, 21): 2, (27, 26): 1, (27, 33): 4, (30, 24): 1, 
 (30, 36): 1, (31, 25): 2, (33, 27): 1, (33, 34): 2, (34, 33): 4, (34, 35): 2, (35, 34): 2, 
 (35, 36): 1, (36, 30): 1, (36, 35): 2}
```

But I am getting an error on execution. Seems like it is due to removing of `None`. I have tried changing `None` by `inf`. Still getting the same error. What should I do now?
Here is the function execution and error:

```
visited,path = dijsktra(g,0)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-c4a3ba9a32e3> in <module>
----> 1 parent,path=dijsktra(g,0)

<ipython-input-25-cd9030508fd7> in dijsktra(graph, initial)
     34 
     35 
---> 36         nodes.remove(min_node)
     37         current_weight = visited[min_node]
     38 

KeyError: None
```

How can I remove the bug? Please anyone resolve this issue. It will be helpful.
Thank you!

**Edits:**
Here is the [link](https://github.com/UJ5/Deep-learning-/blob/main/codes%20for%20pixelate) to the code I used to generate the `g.nodes` and `g.distances`

Comment: Are you sure you copied your code correctly? It seems impossible for `min_code` to be None because of the previous `break` statement **if it is actually at the nesting level you are showing**. Moreover, I don't see how you would ever break out of the `while nodes:` loop unless the `if min_node is None: break` were actually part of that loop.  And this is *not* a minimal, reproducible example. Add the code that creates the nodes and edges so somebody can actually run this when you fix this.

Comment: @Booboo, I have uploaded the link to file with my codes to generate nodes and edges. However, I have fixed the issue now. It was due to the indentation error of 'if min_node is None:' line. This code prints only the distance of the source node to all other nodes and the path of adjacent nodes. Could you please help how can I add get the shortest path printed between source and target node?

Comment: Your final `return` statement is still at the wrong indentation level.

Comment: And the code you posted at the link is missing something (possibly a final ')') and will not compile.

Comment: @Booboo, sorry for the inconvenience. I have updated both the error. I am still trying to print the shortest path between target and source nodes, could you please help me with how can I get that? It will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: And `nodes` is undefined. You need to create a single file with everything combined that also then calls `dijkstra` with *the appropriate arguments*, which your linked code does not. You then need to run that single file ensuring that it runs (and possibly generates your exception). And then you need to update your question by *carefully* copying and pasting the entire (single file) into your question (no links). *That* would be a suitable, minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: If you are working with a *directed graph*, then you should add to `add_edge`: `self.distances[(to_node, from_node)] = distance`. Otherwise, remove from `add_edge`: `self.edges[to_node].append(from_node)`.

Comment: @Booboo, yes I am working on a directed graph so I need both.

Comment: I've taken another hard look at your code. (By the way, I should have said if you want an *undirected* (not *directed*) graph, then you should add to function `add_edge` the following line `self.distances[(from_node, to_node)] = distance`.) But other than a question of efficiency, I don't see anything terribly wrong with it. However, the data you say you have for it makes little sense. Your nodes go from `0, 1, 2 ... 35` but your edges refer to nodes 1 through 36, and that could be your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe your `dijskstra` function is implementing the algorithm correctly. You normally initialize a `dist` (distance) dictionary where the keys are the graph's node values and its values are initialized to infinity (or suitable large value) except for the initial node that is initialized with 0. This dictionary represents the *initial* distance of every node from the initial node. Then every loop iteration looks for an *unvisited* node (which all nodes initially are) looking for the node with the minimal distance from the initial node). The first time through the loop this would be the initial node itself. This node is then removed from the unvisited nodes and the distance from this node to all nodes that neighbor this node are updated. Eventually, all nodes are removed from the unvisited node list and we are done. I have modified what the function returns. Since there is no longer a concept of a visited dictionary, it returns the `dist` dictionary giving the distance to every node:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes = set()
        self.edges = defaultdict(list)
        self.distances = {}

    def add_node(self, value):
        self.nodes.add(value)

    def add_edge(self, from_node, to_node, distance):
        self.edges[from_node].append(to_node)
        self.edges[to_node].append(from_node)
        self.distances[(from_node, to_node)] = distance
        self.distances[(to_node, from_node)] = distance


def dijsktra(graph, initial): # should be dijkstra

    nodes = set(graph.nodes) # unvisted nodes
    path = {}
    dist = {node: 999999999999999 for node in nodes} # assume this is larger than any actual distance
    dist[initial] = 0

    while nodes: # we still have unvisted nodes
        min_node = None
        for node in nodes:
            if min_node is None:
                min_node = node
            elif dist[node] < dist[min_node]:
                min_node = node

        nodes.remove(min_node)
        current_weight = dist[min_node]

        for edge in graph.edges[min_node]:
            weight = current_weight + graph.distances[(min_node, edge)]
            if weight < dist[edge]:
                dist[edge] = weight
                path[edge] = min_node


    return dist, path

"code to generate nodes:"
g=Graph()
g.add_node(1)
g.add_node(2)
g.add_node(3)
g.add_node(4)
g.add_edge(1, 2, 1)
g.add_edge(1, 3, 2)
g.add_edge(2, 4, 5)
g.add_edge(3, 4, 1)

print(dijsktra(g, 1))
```

Prints:

```
({1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3}, {2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 3})
```

**Update**

I thought I would add a modified version that is more efficient. Instead of having all the nodes initially in our "unvisited list" of nodes to process, we maintain a list of nodes whose final distance from the initial node has been computed but its adjacent nodes not yet processed. From this list we always want to select the node whose distance from the initial node has the minimal value. To accomplish this, each node is now a tuple consisting of its distance from the initial node and its node value. These nodes are maintained in a [heap queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) that automatically yields the node with the minimal value:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from heapq import heappop, heappush

class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes = set()
        self.edges = defaultdict(list)
        self.distances = {}

    def add_node(self, value):
        self.nodes.add(value)

    def add_edge(self, from_node, to_node, distance):
        self.edges[from_node].append(to_node)
        self.edges[to_node].append(from_node)
        self.distances[(from_node, to_node)] = distance
        self.distances[(to_node, from_node)] = distance


def dijkstra(graph, initial): # should be dijkstra

    visited = set()
    path = {}
    priority_queue = []
    INFINITY = float('inf')
    distances = {node: INFINITY for node in graph.nodes}
    dist[initial] = 0
    heappush(priority_queue, (0, initial)) # (cost, initial)

    while priority_queue:
        _, min_node = heappop(priority_queue)
        visited.add(min_node)
        current_weight = dist[min_node]
        for edge in graph.edges[min_node]: # this is really a node and not an edge
            if edge in visited:
                continue
            weight = current_weight + graph.distances[(min_node, edge)]
            if weight < dist[edge]:
                dist[edge] = weight
                path[edge] = min_node
                heappush(priority_queue, (weight, edge))

    return dist, path


g = Graph()
g.add_node(1)
g.add_node(2)
g.add_node(3)
g.add_node(4)
g.add_edge(1, 2, 1)
g.add_edge(1, 3, 2)
g.add_edge(2, 4, 5)
g.add_edge(3, 4, 1)

print(dijkstra(g, 1))
```